# In .Net core 2.0 MVC how to apply appsettings.json transformation via nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, appsettings

Given the following appsettings.json file

```
{
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

And an appsettings.json file in a newly created Nuget package

```
{
    "foo" : "bar1"
    "abc" : "123"
}
```

When installing a newly created Nuget package (based on a .csproj package build) how do I end up with the following in the appsettings.json?

```
{
    "foo" : "bar1"
    "abc" : "123"
}
```

**WITHOUT** having to manually add the newly created/installed appsettings.json to the Startup.cs - AddJsonFile directive and without having to worry about environments?

This was easily done in the old Nuget packages, just by providing a Web.config with transforms, in the Nuget package, which then automatically applies the transformation to the current Web.config of the older .NET 4.* MVC applications.

***How do I do this with a JSON settings file???***

Comment: `AddJsonFile` is what makes the framework read the file, how do you expect this to happen if the file isn't read?

Comment: For example... in .NET 4.* apps - To change values in the Web.config file all that was necessary was to include a Web.config transformation file in the Nuget package. This would then transform the Web.config file.

In .NET Core 2.0 apps that use the appsettings.json to provide configuration, there is currently no way for the Nuget package to transform the appsettings.json file so that it includes the necessary key/value pairs required by the Nuget package.You must instruct the Nuget package consumer to add the provided Nuget package configuration file to the Startup.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to achieve this as far as I know. The nuget transforming only works with the projects using "packages.config" file while .Net Core project use package references in project.